# How would you align pictures?

Tags: image-processing

I have a bunch of gif files which would be much more useful as animation. Unfortunately, they are not exactly the same size, and main features (country borders) shift a bit from picture to picture.

[NASA Vision Workbench](http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/project/nasa-vision-workbench/) seems like solution to my problem, but I would love to get something a bit simpler.

Comment: Do you have something on the pictures which is constant - something which should end up in the same place in every frame?

Comment: I have country borders, which are quite similar (but not same due to anti-aliasing) in all pictures. I could extract it manually, but best solution would find that automatically as common shape in all pictures.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your problem?

Comment: Yeah, sure: http://klima.hr/ocjene/2009/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a real answer to your question, but the technique is called "registration".  You may have better luck with a google search on "image registration".

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Although I didn't accept it, I really appreciate hint. It's hard to talk about topic which you don't know terms :-)

Answer (score 0):

a straightforward brute force solution:

- compute minimal size in the set of images
- crop your first image to this size using the paramters you want
- for the next image, try all the possible crops and select the one with maximal correlation with your first image
- repeat until all images are consumed

this question contains an example of image correlation: 
[How to identify symbols in a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507834/how-to-identify-symbols-in-a-image)