# How to identify symbols in a image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a image which contains GUI components such as Button, Label, ComboBox, CheckBox etc. I want to write a Java program to process this image and **identify each components** and their **positions, height and width**. Is it possible? If possible, how should I do?

Thanks;

Kapila

Answer (score 2):

You may use an **[Image Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_correlation).**

Here you have an example in Mathematica:

[image]

The same for Combos:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. It more then can be covered in a simple response, but my suggestion would be to use an algorithm that does edge detection then define what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at javacv, the java binding for opencv.